# How can i make tree to 2D arrays

Tags: algorithm, tree

[image]

I am trying to make tree data structure to 2D array.
I am trying to do it with for loop like this.
childs() function return child nodes array.

```
void makeArray(a 1_level_a)
{
    for(2_level_a : 1_level_a.childs())
    {
        for(3_level_a : 2_level_a.childs())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How can i do it? any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a ready-to-run solution that modifies the standard BFS a little and has been tested with multiple levels. The algorithm shifts the previous rows every time multiple children are added from the current node. Also, it keeps track of the total shift when iterating through a particular level to know where to insert blank cells which bubble up from the children. Finally it propagates down placeholder blank nodes for the case when it hits a leaf before the final level of the tree. When our queue is filled only with these dummy nodes we know we can stop.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.children = []

    def add_children(self, children):
        self.children = children


a = Node("a")
a1 = Node("a1")
a2 = Node("a2")
a3 = Node("a3")
a11 = Node("a11")
a12 = Node("a12")
a31 = Node("a31")


a.add_children([a1, a2, a3])
a2.add_children([a11, a12])
a3.add_children([b1, b2, b3])
a12.add_children([b4])
b2.add_children([b5, b6])

arr = [[a.val]]
queue = [a]
to_process = 1
processed = 0
shifted = 0
while not all(e.val == ""  for e in queue):
    node = queue[0]
    processed+=1
    children = node.children if len(node.children) > 0 else [Node("")]
    if(to_process==processed):
       arr.append(list(map(lambda x: x.val, children)))
       to_process = len(queue)
       queue+=children
       processed = 0
       shifted = 0
    else:
        arr[-1] += list(map(lambda x: x.val, children))
        queue += children
    queue = queue[1:]
    for i in range(0, len(arr)-1):
        arr[i] = arr[i][0:shifted+1] + [""] * (len(children)-1) + arr[i][shifted+1:]
    shifted += len(children)

print("arr: " + str(arr[:-1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write the array row-per-row. The following code assumes that trees only have depth 3:

```cpp
array[0][0] = 1_level_a;
int last_index = 0;

for (2_level_a : 1_level_a.childs()) {
    array[1][last_index] = 2_level_a;
    for (3_level_a : 2_level_a.childs()) {
        array[2][last_index] = 3_level_a;
        last_index++;
    }
    if (2_level_a.childs().size() == 0) {
        last_index++;
    }
}
```

If you need to handle trees of larger depth, you can use recursion:

```cpp
int writeTree(node, depth, last_index) {
    array[depth][last_index] = node;
    for (child : node.childs()) {
        last_index = writeTree(child, depth + 1, last_index);
    }
    if (node.childs().size() == 0) {
        last_index++;
    }
    return last_index;
}

writeTree(1_level_a, 0, 0);
```

Note that this is the same as the above algorithm, but the above algorithm assumes nodes of depth 3 have no children.

Comment: I really like the recursive approach for this actually... good job. Starting with fixed size output array made for a more concise solution.

Comment: Exactly the recursion is not good for large depths as it leads to a stack-overflow exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

For large depth of trees I suggest using a do/while loop with temporary variable for the depth level, to prevent stack-overflow exception. For example, if you would want to transfor huge structure stored as JSON object to a 2 dimensional array. Use case - when transforming coordinates and would want to build paths - I would use the following JS code, but in the most of the OOP languages may look same sintaxis. Later on, the result can be sorted or the dimensions can be rotated additionally.

```
function getPaths(tree) {
  const result = [];
  let nodes = [{ element: tree, path: ['root'] }];

  do {
    const newNodes = [];

    // 1. Loop over the nodes
    _.forEach(nodes, (branch) => {
      const track = branch.path;

      // 2. Get the children
      _.mapValues(branch.element, (child, childName) => {
        const newTrack = _.cloneDeep(track);
        // 3. Put down the current path to that point
        newTrack.push(childName);
        // 4. In case there's a child - create new job for the loop
        if (!_.isNil(child)) {
          newNodes.push({ element: child, path: newTrack });
          return;
        }
        // 5. In case the end of the branch is reached - store the path to result
        _.set(result, result.length, newTrack);
      });
    });
    nodes = newNodes;

    // 6. Continue until the maximum depth is reached
  } while (!_.isEmpty(nodes));

  return result;
}
```

**Note: this code will sort the result by the shortest dimensions first.**

Input:

```
{
  avenue1: {
    street2: {
       laneA: undefined,
    },
  },
  avenue2: {
    street12: {
      streetA: {
        laneA: undefined,
        LaneB: undefined,
        laneC: undefined,
      },
      streetB: {
        laneA: undefined,
        LaneB: undefined,
      },
      streetC: {
        laneA: undefined,
      },
    },
  },
  avenue3: {
    street26: {
      alley13: undefined,
      alley15: undefined,
    },
  },
  highway: undefined,
}
```

Result:

```
[
  [ 'root', 'highway' ],
  [ 'root', 'avenue1', 'street2', 'laneA' ],
  [ 'root', 'avenue3', 'street26', 'alley13' ],
  [ 'root', 'avenue3', 'street26', 'alley15' ],
  [ 'root', 'avenue2', 'street12', 'streetA', 'laneA' ],
  [ 'root', 'avenue2', 'street12', 'streetA', 'LaneB' ],
  [ 'root', 'avenue2', 'street12', 'streetA', 'laneC' ],
  [ 'root', 'avenue2', 'street12', 'streetB', 'laneA' ],
  [ 'root', 'avenue2', 'street12', 'streetB', 'LaneB' ],
  [ 'root', 'avenue2', 'street12', 'streetC', 'laneA' ]
]
```